# tying to make a indicator based on count in R

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, indicator

```
a   b   c   d   e   f   G
0   1   0   1   1   0   0
0   1   1   0   1   0   0
1   1   1   1   1   0   0
0   1   0   1   1   0   0
0   1   0   1   1   0   0
```

Consider this table
I want to mutate a column with yes and no, "yes" if all columns(a:G) combined are greater than 3 and "no" if less than or equal to 3.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Provide more insight on the question and what output you want.

Comment: `ifelse(rowSums(df,1:7]) > 3, 'yes', 'no')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```r
library(dplyr)

table |> 
  mutate(sum_bigger_than_three = rowSums(across(a:G)) > 3)
```

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 5 × 8
      a     b     c     d     e     f     G sum_bigger_than_three
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>                
1     0     1     0     1     1     0     0 FALSE                
2     0     1     1     0     1     0     0 FALSE                
3     1     1     1     1     1     0     0 TRUE                 
4     0     1     0     1     1     0     0 FALSE                
5     0     1     0     1     1     0     0 FALSE
```